# Issue comparing dates with the same format

Tags: sql-server, date, ms-access, format, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to filter a form with a interval of time

the start date and end date are both in a textbox with this format `dd/mm/yyyy`

My query in `VBA` looks like this

```
WHERE (Format([SalesCallDate],'dd/mm/yyyy') BETWEEN #" & Format(txtStartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#
 AND #" & Format(txtEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#)"
```

I can't figure out why when the interval is `01/12/2012` to `21/12/2012`, I got dates like `15/08/1991`. That's why I wanted to be explicit with the format.

the output for the SQL query is
`WHERE (Format([SalesCallDate],'dd/mm/yyyy') BETWEEN #01/12/2012# AND #21/12/2012#)`

I tried with and without the format.

Am I missing something?

**NOTE**: `SalesCallDate` is a `DateTime` field in a SQL Server linked table

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like txtStartDate and txtEndDate are both unbound text boxes.  Set their format properties to a date format.

[image: text box with Format set to General Date]

With a date format and the "Show Date Picker" property set to "For dates", Access versions >= 2007 will enable that date picker feature for your text boxes.  If your users like that, this is a side benefit of that format property.

Anyway the date format will allow Access and VBA to interpret those text box values as Date/Time data type:

```
? TypeName(Forms!frmDateRange!txtStartDate.Value)
Date
```

Then since `SalesCallDate` is Date/Time type, your `WHERE` clause can compare the field directly to the text box values.

```
WHERE SalesCallDate BETWEEN
        Forms!frmDateRange!txtStartDate
    AND Forms!frmDateRange!txtEndDate
```

Or if your form has code which builds a string containing your SQL statement, and you want Date/Time literals for the date range ...

```
"WHERE SalesCallDate BETWEEN " & _
    Format(Me.txtStartDate, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
    " AND " & Format(Me.txtEndDate, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
```

Comment: Thank you! It works only with the # inside the format pattern. I would have never found that by myself.